# Ignore logging.basicConfig in third party module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am importing a third party module that I don't have control over and can't change the source. It does a `logging.basicConfig()` which is messing up my own logger configuration. I have tried giving a different 'name' to my logger using `self.logger = logging.getLogger('some_random_name')` which is resulting in every log message printed twice, once with my format, and once with the format set by the `basicConfig` in that third party module.

Is there a way to ignore the basicConfig from the imported module?

Comment: Have you tried logging.getLogger('some_random_name').setLevel(logging.FATAL) ?

Comment: @montardon yes, I am already doing this `self.logger = loggin.getLogger('whatever'); self.logger.setLevel(logLevel)` where `logLevel` is based on cmd line args (whether user wants debug mode logging or not)

Comment: You can just delete that handler `logging.root.handlers = []`.

Comment: @Sraw that did it! Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig()` implicitly add handlers to the root logger, so you can just delete those handlers by `logging.root.handlers = []`.

---

Further, the root logger may set to an unwanted level, you can also simply set it by `logging.root.setLevel(what_ever_you_want)`.

---

Even further, if you call `logging.info`, `logging.error` etc. without configuring the root logger first, a `basicConfig()` is called internally, and so a `StreamHandler` will be implicitly added to the root logger.